# How to reapply after a UK visa refusal under Appendix V 4.3 (a), (b) and (c)?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

I am a Filipina and am employed. My boyfriend is a Bulgarian citizen, self-employed, living and working in London since 2011. According to my boyfriend, Bulgarians can come and go to the UK, and I did research, too. It says Bulgarians and Romanians can work freely in the UK since the restrictions have been lifted on January 1, 2014.

I must admit we didn't submit any proof of our relationship, except for his invitation. We submitted his bank statements, tenancy agreement, residence documentation, copy of passport, and driver's license.

I was wondering why they question the status of my sponsor in UK when we provided the residence documentation and tenancy agreement.

[image: Refusal letter]

My concern is how can we improve our next application for a Standard Visitor visa to the UK?

What are the documents that will satisfy them that my boyfriend is legally present during my visit and that he is willing to support my trip?

Thanks for suggestions and advice. I'll share it with him. We are now working on additional evidence. That was the very first time we applied for visa and yeah we failed to present strong evidence. At first we weren't sure what kind of evidence would satisfy. We are now improving the invitation letter, then he plans to submit additional documents to support the application, like registration certificate of his vehicle and it's motor insurance, picture of his place, national insurance record for the last five years, job contract, our photos together, 'phone calls and emails. Plus we will resubmit the documents we submitted in the first application, like tenancy agreement, copy of our passports, bank statements, UK Home Office residence documentation.

Do you think it will satisfy them this time?

I plan to change the date as well, originally it was April 11 - May 15, 2017 now I want it to be April 11 - May 7, 2017 and instead of £1,500 we'll make it £1,100.

Do you think it is OK to change the date and budget/funds?

Because I need to be home for my mother's 60th birthday and help organize.

Do I have to explain why I'm changing the date and the budget?

I really want to get the visa, I want to be with him during my summer vacation, and to meet his family.

Comment: nope... he works self employed and all legal

Comment: Being self-employed doesn't imply that it's legal. If he's permitted to work, that can be self-employed or as an employee; if he's not permitted to work, then he can't be self-employed or an employee.

Comment: he has a residence documentation and it was stated there he is self-employed

Comment: @David Richerby yeah I am new to this...

Comment: Thank you for your help and advice, I got my visa yesterday.

Answer (score 5):

You were refused a UK Standard Visitor Visa and you have embedded your refusal notice (thanks for that by the way).  The notice seems pretty straight-forward, they got you on 4.2 (a+b+c) and those paragraphs are laid out at [Immigration Rules Appendix V](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules).

> My bf is a Bulgarian citizen, self-employed, and living and working in
>   London since 2011.. and according to my bf they can come and go of UK,
>   and I did research too and it says Bulgarian and Romanian can work
>   freely in the UK since the restrictions have been lifted in January 1
>   2014..

Well, not exactly. Bulgarian nationals can exercise treaty rights in the UK and as a self-employed person they would expect to see evidence of that.  He did not, apparently, provide satisfactory evidence. Is his insurance up-to-date? His taxes? Is he a self-sufficient person?

> What are the documents that will satisfy them that my boyfriend is
>   legally present during my visit and that he is willing to support my
>   trip?

He should submit evidence that he is lawfully exercising treaty rights. For example his insurance, his taxes (VAT and self-assessment), his bank statements and the like.

He should also provide some evidence that he intends upon maintaining a relationship with you (and you with him). Some evidence, for example, that you are in an ongoing relationship and have a history of meeting each other personally.

Comment: @ Gayot Fow thanks for suggestions and advices I'll share it with him...